# Using yield to async a Flask Response, but adding header information at the end of the long async call?

Tags: python, asynchronous, heroku, flask

I have a particularly large task that takes ~60 seconds to complete.  Heroku routers send a timeout error after 30 seconds if nothing is returned, so using a `yield` statement helps solve that:

````
def foo():
    while not isDone:
        print("yield")
        yield " "
        time.sleep(10)
return Response(foo(), mimetype='text/html')```
````

(or something similar)

And that works all well and good, except in my case, at the end of my very long task, it makes a decision on where to `302` forward next.  It's easy enough to set a forwarding location:

```
response = Response(foo(), 302, mimetype='text/html')
response.headers['Location'] = '/bar'
return response
```

except that in this example `/bar` is static, and I need to assign that dynamically, and only at the end of the very long process.

So is there a way to dynamically assign the forwarding location at the end of the very long async process?

Comment: Use celery to do the time consuming task and use ajax to poll the result.

Comment: @stamaimer While Celery/Rabbit would be a good choice, I'm limited in what I'm allowed to use (everything requires a hierarchy of approval from the client, and waiting 2-3 weeks for a size-2 bug simply won't do).  If it can't be done with Flask alone, so be it, but I need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure I'm interpreting this correctly. You have a request that generates something and issues a redirect. The generation takes a long time, triggering the Heroku timeout. You want to get around the time out, somehow.

Can you do this with Flask alone, with the constraint of the Heroku routing tier? Sort of. Note, though, that the simple "keep alive" you are doing fails because it results in an invalid HTTP response. Once you start sending anything that is *not* a header, you can't send a header (i.e., the redirect).

Your two options -

- **Polling.** Launch an async job, pre-calculate the URL for the job result, but have it guarded by a "monitor" of some kind (e.g., check the job and display "In progress", refreshing every 2-5 seconds until it's done). You have a worker dyno that is used to calculate the result. Ordinarily, I'd say "Redis + Python RQ" for a fast start, but if you can't add any new server-side dependencies, a simple database queue table could suffice.
- **Pushing.** Use an add-on like [Pusher](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/pusher). No new server-side dependencies, just an account (which has a low-cost entry option) If that's not an option, roll a [WebSocket](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets)-based solution.

In general, spending some time to do a good async return will pay off in the long run. It's one of the single best performance enhancements to make to any site - return fast, give the user a responsive experience. You do have to spawn the async task in another process or thread, in order to free up request threads for other responses.